# How to change the format of the date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date as "1-Jun". How can I convert this to 01/06? I am using Strptime. I thought this is going to be easy but it is not.

Error that I am getting: time data '1-Jun' does not match format '%d-%Mmm'. 
This is the command I am using. Can anyone help me with this?

`datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%Mmm').strftime('%m/%d')`

Answer (score 2):

There's no such format as `%Mmm`, what you need to match `Jun` is `%b` ("Locale's abbreviated month name"). Also, if you want `01/06` rather than `06/01` it is going to be `'%d/%m'` in `strftime`:

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('1-Jun', '%d-%b').strftime('%d/%m'))
```